# changing body class based on user's local time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a body class of 'day' if it's 6am-5pm and 'night' if "else" based on the user's local time.

I tried the following but it didn't work. Any ideas?

In the head:

```
<script>
function setTimesStyles() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if(currentTime > 5 && currentTime < 17) {
        document.body.className = 'day';
    }
    else {
        document.body.className = 'night';
    }
}
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<body onload="setTimeStyles();">
```

Also, is there a more elegant way to achieve what I need?

This site is on Wordpress btw.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. What browser(s) exhibit the problem? What exactly is the problem? Have you tried using a JavaScript debugger? It's most likely a time zone problem, if it's not adding the right class at the right time.

Comment: I'm working in Firefox. I can't seem to get the class name to show up for the body tag. I'll try debugging although I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: It seems likely that it *is* working, it just isn't doing what you think it should, either because of CSS, clock settings, or time-zone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Shouldn't my code add a class of 'day' or 'night' to the body tag? What difference would the css, clock settings, or time-zone make? Sorry, I'm relatively new to all of this. I tried debugging with Firebug and I don't seem to be getting any errors.

Comment: Where do you expect to see this new class?  You will only be able to verify that it is there via a debugger like Firebug.  It will not show up in the tag in the source if that is what you expect.

Comment: @John - Don't know if this is just a typo in the question but the function name in the onload attribute is different to the function name in the script block: setTimeStyles vs setTimesStyles.

Comment: @Jeff I have Firebug but where do I go to check to verify that the tag is showing? Also, Alohci and Shaun thanks for the hint on the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typing mistake in your function

```
function setTimesStyles() {  
    ...
}
```

should be

```
function setTimeStyles() {  
    ...
}
```

Either make the above change or update your body call to be the exact spelling of the function.

Other than that I would use something more unubtrosive to set the class name of the body tag. Instead of calling the function directly. I would recommend using one of the many javascript frameworks out there to detect when the DOM is ready to be traversed. Once you know that the DOM has been constructed you can execute the necessary code. An example is jquery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function which you can tie into in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeStyles();
    ... // or any other code you want to execute when the DOM is ready.
});
```

The frameworks abstract a lot of the details you would usually need to know about getting certain things to work in different browsers. Doing things in a more unobtrusive manner also has the added benefit of giving you better separation between your javascript and HTML.